# Why does .Net NPOI CloneStyleFrom() not correctly apply Font BoldWeight?

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

I'm using .Net NPOI to create some spreadsheets.
I'm having an issue with cloning cell styles.

I open an existing Excel spreadsheet, and from a specific worksheet I get
the style from an existing cell.

Consider the following:

```
var sourceRow = sourceWorksheet.GetRow(sourceRowNum) as XSSFRow;
var oldCell = sourceRow.GetCell(i) as XSSFCell;
var font = oldCell.CellStyle.GetFont(workbook);
```

When I examine the **BoldWeight** of the font, I see that it's set to **700**.
Next, I've created a new cell and I attempt to use the cloned style from the old cell.

```
newRow = sourceWorksheet.CreateRow(destinationRowNum) as XSSFRow;
var newCell = newRow.CreateCell(2) as XSSFCell;
newCell.CellStyle.CloneStyleFrom(oldCell.CellStyle as XSSFCellStyle);
var font1 = newCell.CellStyle.GetFont(workbook);
```

If I compare font and font1 above, I see that they are identical and they both have a **BoldWeight** of **700**.

When I write the spreadsheet out to file, open and examine the file, I see that the **BoldWeight** has not been applied.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: If I can copy and paste it into a console app and run it, it would qualify as a [mcve].

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662756/formatting-error-in-npoi